# Get the title of annotation clicked at map

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

Hi I have this code for clicking an annotationView, when clicking the annotation I want to know what the title of the annotation is, is this possible?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        if (control as? UIButton)?.buttonType == UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure {
            mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: false)
            performSegueWithIdentifier("moreInfo", sender: view)
        }
    }

func setPins(){
        for restaurant in restaurantObjects{
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(restaurant.latitude, restaurant.longitude)
            annotation.title = restaurant.name
            annotation.subtitle = "This is a phoneStation"
            mapRestaurants.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Access to the `annotation` property of the annotationView on the delegate method, and get the title: `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) { NSString *title = annotationView.annotation.title;
}`

Comment: Not working.. @PabloA.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete the word "view" after "annotationView", it's the solution you posted behind

Comment: oh, okay :) @PabloA.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if (control as? UIButton)?.buttonType == UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure {
            var title = view.annotation?.title
            print(title)
            mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: false)
            performSegueWithIdentifier("moreInfo", sender: view)
        }
    }
```